Spring Webflux: Custom serialization of complex objects as request parameters for a reactive webclient declaratively defined through annotations
As part of rewriting functionality into a reactive Spring 6 applicaiton (Kotlin), I am implementing a declaratively defined WebClient (by the approach described here).
All went well until I got to an endpoint having one of its request parameters defined as a complex filter object. This was previously implemented using a Feign client, having a structure like this:
override fun someResource(
    @RequestParam("filter") filter: ComplexFilterClass
): Response<List<Resorce>>

I would prefer to be able to keep the signature unchanged, defining it as
@GetExchange("/url/to/resource")
override suspend fun someResource(
    @RequestParam("filter") filter: ComplexFilterClass
): Response<List<Resorce>>

The problem occurs when Spring is trying to serialize the filter object to a request parameter string, resulting in the error

org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam com.example.ComplexFilterClass] to type [java.lang.String]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:294)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:185)

I have not been able to figure out how to define a converter to get Spring to understand how to serialize the request parameter. I have tried registering a Spring converter component that converts it to string, without any different result. I also tried adding codecs in the WebClient builder with
    .codecs {
        it.customCodecs().register(Jackson2JsonDecoder())
        it.customCodecs().register(Jackson2JsonEncoder())
    }

I would appreciate if anyone knows how to acheive this. If not, I guess there is still an option to just change the client definition into taking a String, and converting it somewhere else first. But if possible I would prefer a more automatic approach.
